# AngularJS Image Input get DataURL

Tags: angularjs, windows, image

I'm using AngularJS in a website, and on site is a form that allows a user to select an image from their local file system, and hopefully then get the dataurl from that image. I am looking for a way to do this in the most simple way possible. I would then like to display that image somewhere on the webpage. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            <input id="backgroundImageUpload" type="file" onchange="previewFile()">
            <br>
            <img id="backgroundImagebleh" src="" height="200" alt="Image preview...">

            <script>
                function previewFile() {
                    var preview = document.querySelector('#backgroundImagebleh');
                    var file = document.querySelector('#backgroundImageUpload').files[0];
                    var reader = new FileReader();

                    reader.addEventListener("load", function() {
                        preview.src = reader.result;
                        $scope.backgroundFile = reader.result;
                    }, false);

                    if (file) {
                        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using the following directive https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload, there are good examples.

Comment: But this actually uploads to a server, and I would like to just get a data url and preview it on the local version of the website.